# Getting unique items from a two dimensional array python

Tags: python

Here, the array has two dimensions(characters and numbers) and i wanna get the unique items by only respecting second dimension which are numbers in `myList` below. I have done this by using an additional list(`a_list`), but i am looking for a better way.

```
myList=[]

myList.append(("a",0))
myList.append(("b",0))
myList.append(("b",0))
myList.append(("a",1))
myList.append(("a",1))

distinctmyList =[]
a_list=[]

for  i in myList:
    a_list.append(i[1])
distinctmyList.append(list(set(a_list)))
print distinctmyList
```

The output:

```
[[0, 1]]
```

which are unique items of `myList` by respecting second items which are numbers(0s and 1s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do something like this

```
print list(set(zip(*myList)[1]))
```

**EDIT:** As per your requirements in the comments

```
myList=[]

myList.append(("a",0))
myList.append(("b",0))
myList.append(("b",0))
myList.append(("a",1))
myList.append(("a",1))

Dict = {}

for Data in myList :
    Dict.setdefault(Data[1], []).append(Data[0])

print [(values[0], key) for key, values in Dict.items()]
```

**Output**

```
[('a', 0), ('a', 1)]
```

**EDIT1:** Solution which preserves order

```
myList=[]

myList.append(("a",0))
myList.append(("b",0))
myList.append(("b",0))
myList.append(("a",2))
myList.append(("a",1))
myList.append(("a",1))

Dict   = {}
Unique = []
for Data in myList :
    Dict.setdefault(Data[1], []).append(Data[0])
    if Data[1] not in Unique: Unique.append(Data[1])

print [(Dict[Data][0], Data) for Data in Unique]
```

**Output**

```
[('a', 0), ('a', 2), ('a', 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks, using dict is a good idea. one more thing, how to keep the original order. I guess set function may change it.

Comment: But we dont use `set` here. And what do you mean by original order?

Comment: I meant setdefault. Add this item at middle of the list myList.append(("a",2)), the result should be [('a',0),('a',2),('a',1)] but it gives [('a',0),('a',1),('a',2)] which is not in the correct order if you consider the order of appending items in the list.

Comment: You'd be better off making `Unique` a `set` (much faster lookups). If you're interested in a way of doing this without loops, check out my updated answer. Also, have a look at PEP8; only class names are supposed to be in PascalCase and everything else lowercase!

Comment: @ThijsvanDien In my solution, I use `Unique` as a list, to maintain the order. But your solution looks lot cleaner that mine.

Comment: @thefourtheye Well, in that case I think you should use a `list` instead of a `dict`. You would get something like `for Data in myList: if Data[1] not in Unique: List.append(Data); Unique.add(Data[1])`. Which would then be clearer if `Unique` was named `Seen`. But please have a look at naming, as said before.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) to only get unique items. But first you need to extract the numbers, which you can do using tuple expansion in a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

```
>>> print set(number for character, number in myList)
set([0, 1])
```

**Update**

Here's a version that meets your changed requirements.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> lst = [('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('b', 0), ('a', 2), ('a', 1), ('a', 1)]
>>> print list(reversed(OrderedDict((x[1], x) for x in reversed(lst)).values())) 
[('a', 0), ('a', 2), ('a', 1)]
```

Comment: One thing, how can I keep the corresponding first item in the unique list. For example, set( ["a",0],["a",1])

Comment: @CoKoder What if the input is ("a", 0), ("b", 0), ("a", 1")

Comment: @thefourtheye the output will be ("a",0),("a",1), just keeping the first item with second one.

Comment: @CoKoder Changing the requirements all the time is not much appreciated. Next time when asking a question, try to be more precise from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you're looking for something like this:

```
>>> print list(set([x[1] for x in myList]))
[0, 1]
```